# How to represent real world in jmeter while jmeter waits the previous response to send a new request?

Tags: jmeter

when i want to send 10 requests (all the same request) in one second while running a stress test, but jmeter waits the previous response, what should i do if the response time is nearly 2 seconds.

in real world ten users may hit the same page at the same time, but in jmeter how to do this?

Does the jmeter have this ability or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add 10 threads in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group):

[image]

If you want to ensure that the request start at exactly the same moment additionally add a [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) and set the number of simulated users to group by to 10

[image]

Comment: thank you for the useful reply. if i want a changing variable instead of a constant value in grouping field, how to do? i want the value always equal the number of actaul threads. i am using ultimate thread group and the value is always changing running the test.